# A regular expression to match a string and if that string ends with specific character, then don't match

Tags: python, regex

I'm having trouble trying to make a regular expression to match a string `ka toki.*` (for example `ka toki` or `ka toki knfjk`), but not match if the first symbol after `toki` is `a`.

So in other words I'm trying to match these:

```
ka toki
ka toki sadbkhbhd habsd
ka tokijhvkhsd
```

But not these:

```
ka tokia
ka tokia asdibasd
ka tokiaasdgjkn
```

Comment: What is the regex engine? Programming language? Also, should `ka tokik` match?

Comment: It is Python and yes

Comment: It should be either `^ka toki(?!a).*$` or `^ka toki(?:[^a].*)?$` (I assume the whole string should match the pattern).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `^ka toki(?!a).*$` works perfect, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use alternation to select both the case where no characters follow and the case where a character other than A follows:

```
ka toki($|[^A].*)
```

See https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

Answer (score 1):

To match a whole string starting with `ka toki` that is not followed with `a`, you may use

```
re.match(r'ka toki(?!a).*$', s)
```

Python's `re.match` anchors the match at the start of the string, thus, you may omit the `^` anchor at the start of the `^ka toki(?!a).*$` pattern.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/suOEoq/1).

**Pattern details**

- `^`  - start of the string (implicit in [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match))
- `ka toki` - a literal substring
- `(?!a)` - a negative [**lookahead**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that fails the match if the `a` char follows the `ka toki` substring
- `.*` - the rest of the line, 0+ chars other than a newline (you may yse `re.DOTALL` or `re.S` to make it match across lines)
- `$` - end of the string (actually, it can be omitted if you expect only single line matches).

Note that the same can be achieved without a lookaround, by using a negated character class within an optional group:

```
re.match(r'ka toki(?:[^a].*)?$', s)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/suOEoq/2).

Here, `(?:[^a].*)?` is an optional non-capturing group that matches 1 or 0 occurrences of any char but `a` (with `[^a]`) and then `.*` matches the rest of the string.